# How can I create a Virtual Harddrive off an existing installation?

Tags: windows-server-2003, virtualization

I have a working Windows Server 2003 (Small Business Edition) and I'd like to create a virtual machine of this installation. I'm planning to use MS Virtual Server. How can I get this done?

Answer (score 3):

The [Virtual Server 2005 Migration Toolkit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualserver/bb676674.aspx) should allow you to do this. It is designed to assist in moving from a physical to a virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

If 2008 is an option, it's possible to create a VM of this server while it's up and running using Windows 2008 Server (the Hyper V role is the upgrade/replacement to MS Virtual Server) and System Center Virtual Machine Manager.